# Can I use "lodash" library "invoke" method to call an async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, lodash

My current code is like below,

```
import { invoke } from 'lodash';
...
... do something ...
...
const result = await jsonResponse.json();
```

Instead can I use `invoke` and write like this?

```
import { invoke } from 'lodash';
...
... do something ...
...
const result = await invoke(jsonResponse, 'json');
```

Comment: You should be able to do that. Did you try it and face any problem?

Comment: I did not try it. But I have seen `lodash` methods used with await. I want to know whether this could cause any trouble.